# How to check for exhaustiveness of product types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, pattern-matching, destructuring, type-safety, algebraic-data-types

It's very easy to check for exhaustiveness of sum types in TypeScript.

```js
type Sum =
    | { tag: 'num'; value: number }
    | { tag: 'str'; value: string };

const len = (sum: Sum): number => {
    switch (sum.tag) {
        case 'num': return sum.value;
        case 'str': return sum.value.length;
        default: throw new Error(`Unhandled sum ${sum satisfies never}`);
    }
};
```

Now, if I add a new variant to the `Sum` type then `sum` will no longer be assignable to `never`. Hence, we'll get a compile time error for non-exhaustiveness.

How can I do the same for product types in TypeScript? Consider the following example.

```js
type Product = {
    num: number;
    str: string;
};

const repeat = (product: Product): string => {
    const { num, str } = product;
    return str.repeat(num);
};
```

Now, if I add a new property to the `Product` type then I want the TypeScript compiler to report an error for non-exhaustiveness, because the new property hasn't been de-structured and used. How do I do that?

Plus points if the code throws a runtime error for non-exhaustiveness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start by throwing a runtime error for non-exhaustiveness. We can do this by destructuring the rest properties, and throwing an error if it has one or more enumerable keys.

```js
const repeat = (product: Product): string => {
    const { num, str, ...props } = product;
    if (Object.keys(props).length > 0) {
        throw new Error(`Unhandled props ${props}`);
    }
    return str.repeat(num);
};
```

Next, in order for TypeScript to check for exhaustiveness at compile time we can do the following.

```js
type IsEmptyObject<A> = {} extends A ? unknown : never;

const repeat = (product: Product): string => {
    const { num, str, ...props } = product;
    if (Object.keys(props).length > 0) {
        throw new Error(
          `Unhandled props ${props satisfies IsEmptyObject<typeof props>}`
        );
    }
    return str.repeat(num);
};
```

Here's how it works.

1. The empty object type `{}` is only assignable to `A` iff `A` is an empty object.
2. Hence, when `props` is an empty object then the type of `IsEmptyObject<typeof props>` is `unknown` and everything is all right.
3. However, when `props` is not an empty object then the type of `IsEmptyObject<typeof props>` is `never` and we get a compile time error.

Thus, the above code will check for exhaustiveness of the product type at the time of de-structuring. If a new property is added to the `Product` type then `props` will no longer be assignable to `IsEmptyObject<typeof props>` and we'll get a compile time error for non-exhaustiveness.

Additionally, you can turn on the [`@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unused-vars.md) rule to make sure that all the de-structured properties are used. Make sure to set the `ignoreRestSiblings` option to `false`.

Comment: AFAIK, there are several workarounds in typescript. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXzIZZDq2hE) you can find a nice one.

Comment: Can you send me the link to the relevant timestamp in the video?

Comment: Please see [github repo](https://github.com/macsikora/elm-in-ts/blob/main/elm-in-ts.ts)

Comment: That is very complex code. It's especially difficult to understand because there are no comments. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: typescript conditional types are hard to read, especially if they are nested. It works in the same way as nested conditional statements in pure js. If you have 5 nested conditional statements it is hard to read even if you have 20 years of experience. Same story about TS conditional types. However, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286) you can find an explanation to `UnionToIntersection` and [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) you can find TS official documentation to conditional types

Comment: You can write to the author of this code, maybe he has some article with more explanation

Comment: All right, but what does this have to do with checking for exhaustiveness of product types? Converting a union type to an intersection type doesn't help me here.